# Is there a print-friendly/mobile page redirector for Firefox?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, redirection

When clicking through search results, you often end up on a print-friendly page or a mobile page rather than the full page you were after. Using an add-on like [Redirector](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/redirector/), one can write rules to automatically redirect these URL patterns to the desired location, but with so many different software packages driving the web these days, this is highly impractical. Is there an actively maintained Firefox add-on or userscript with a built-in ruleset for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Usually it can be done easily from within the webpages themselves.
I.E. When you are viewing mobile pages, often there is a link "go to non-mobile version of the site", "go to full site", or something similar.

Comment: Valid, but I'd like to automate it. One can easily toss every new ad server they come across into their hosts file as well, but I think most would still prefer to use Adblock Plus.